# No styles applied to angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

Tags: css, angular, angular6

Im using [angular-2-dropdown-multiselect](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect) with my Angular project with Angular CLI.

I was able to get it working in my project, but for some reason there are no styles applied. I have installed bootstrap 3 and FontAwesome as well since the documentation claims these are dependencies.

**Update**

Please note that updating bootstrap is not an option for me as the project is quite large and the rest of the layouts are based on bootstrap3

Can someone help me figure out whats going on?

[Here is a demo of the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssbbhm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: did you add the both inside your config json?

Comment: You mean the angular.json? yes I did: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssbbhm?file=angular.json

Comment: Iam added answer pls check once and let me know.If any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the [releases](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/releases) of angular-2-dropdown-multiselect I noticed that Boostrap 4 support was introduced with version 1.7.

I tried downgrading to version 1.6.3 and the styling issues were fixed. So I guess the documentation was wrong about support for bootstrap 3 with the latest release.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your path properly other wise it will not work and update your boostrap to latest version it will work
Check your example i have edited https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyg8hy

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
```

Comment: hmm, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the path. If you click and open the dropdown, you'll see that there are styling issues there

Comment: may be your boostrap is old version update to boostrap 4.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyg8hy

Comment: thanks but unfortunately, updating bootstrap is not an option for me as the project is quite large and the rest of the layouts are based on bootstrap3

Answer (score 0):

Here iam updated your stackblitz iam added bootstrap in index.html file
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3jrnu

it's worked perfect

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>loading</my-app>
</body>
```

if your not use bootstrap 4 use this

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

[image]

Edit:-

Note:-
 angular-2-dropdown-multiselect used bootstrap 4 only. see the screenshot,

[image]
screenshot,

Edit2:-
index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but unfortunately, updating bootstrap is not an option for me as the project is quite large and the rest of the layouts are based on bootstrap3

Comment: I noticed that you have changed the bootstrap version referred in the index.html, but still the issue exists and also including scripts on the head section is not how things should be done when using NPM and Angular CLI

Comment: The readme clearly mentions that the library supports bootstrap 3 https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect#dependencies

Comment: Maybe it is an issue with the library, I will open an issue on github. Thanks for your time

Comment: yeah iam seen. But that plugin not used bootstrap 3. If use angular cli go node modules folder and visit that package index.html

Comment: Hey try to replace bootstrap 3 css in that node-modules package index.html file.Maybe its solved.Just try once.

Comment: I downgraded the angular-2-dropdown-multiselect plugin and it worked. Thanks for your time